# path on a remote disk Mac OS x

Tags: java, sqlite, sqlexception

I have done a Java program, who access a SQLite DB, located on the local MAC Disk. So far so good.

Now I would move the DB on my network drive (Sinology) that I can access and use with the OSx.
I just moved the DB file, but trying to access with my program I get an error like the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to '//192.168.1.99/homes/Ali_Ele/DischiArchivio/dischidB.db': '/192.168.1.99' does not exist
```

But the path exists, of course. 
Could you help me to fix this issue?

I included the code with the issue, the commented `String` works perfectly, while the other one does not

```
public class Dischimain  {
private static Statement stm = null;
private static Connection c = null; 
private static String sql = null;

 /*
  * private static String  path = 
  *    "jdbc:sqlite://Users/eco/Documents/dischiArchivio/dischidB.db"; 
  * private static String pathd = 
  *     "//Users/eco/Documents/dischiArchivio/dischidB.db";
  */
private static String path =  
"jdbc:sqlite://192.168.1.99/homes/Ali_Ele/DischiArchivio/dischidB.db";
private static String pathd = 
    "//192.168.1.99/homes/Ali_Ele/DischiArchivio/dischidB.db";
               }
```